# Getting error when trying to load json data to angular

Tags: angularjs, gallery

I am trying implement a simple photo gallery using angularjs, here I need to load images from json file and display them on my view file, when I click on a tab the images should display

Controller

```
$scope.loadGallery = function(){

        $scope.url = '/dev/images.json';
        $scope.images = [];
        $scope.imageCategories = [];
        $scope.currentImage = {};

        $scope.fetch = function () {
            alert($scope.url);
            $http.get($scope.url).success($scope.handleImagesLoaded);

        }
        function handleImagesLoaded(data, status) {

            $scope.images = data;
            $scope.currentImage = _.first($scope.images);
            $scope.imageCategories = _.uniq(_.pluck($scope.images, 'category'));
        }



        $scope.setCurrentImage = function (image) {
            $scope.currentImage = image;
        };

        $scope.fetch();
    }
```

HTML

```
<tab heading="Photos" ng-click="loadGallery()">
    <div id="albumImage">
    asdasd
        <img ng-src="{{currentImage.image}}" alt="{{currentImage.description}}">
    </div>

    <div id="thumbWrapper">
        <ul id="thumbList">
            <li ng-repeat="image in images" ng-click="setCurrentImage(image)">
                <img ng-src="{{image.thumbnail}}" alt="{{image.description}}">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</tab>
```

images.json

```
[
{"category" : "ones",   "image" : "http://localhost:9080/dev/lib/img/contact-img.png", "thumbnail" : "http://localhost:9080/dev/lib/img/contact-img.png", "description" : "Image 01 description"},
{"category" : "twos",   "image" : "http://localhost:9080/dev/lib/img/contact-img2.png", "thumbnail" : "http://localhost:9080/dev/lib/img/contact-img2.png", "description" : "Image 02 description"},
{"category" : "threes", "image" : "http://localhost:9080/dev/lib/img/contact-img3.png", "thumbnail" : "http://localhost:9080/dev/lib/img/contact-img3.png", "description" : "Image 03 description"}

]
```

But when I call loadGallery function I am getting following error

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at http://localhost:9080/dev/lib/js/angular.js:7733:11
at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:9080/dev/lib/js/angular.js:11100:81)
at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:9080/dev/lib/js/angular.js:11100:81)
at http://localhost:9080/dev/lib/js/angular.js:11186:26
at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:9080/dev/lib/js/angular.js:12175:28)
at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:9080/dev/lib/js/angular.js:12004:31)
at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:9080/dev/lib/js/angular.js:12279:24)
at done (http://localhost:9080/dev/lib/js/angular.js:7991:45)
at completeRequest (http://localhost:9080/dev/lib/js/angular.js:8196:7)
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange     (http://localhost:9080/dev/lib/js/angular.js:8137:11)
```

What is the problem here? any help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$scope.handleImagesLoaded` is undefined, you haven't assign the `handleImagesLoaded` function into `$scope`.

Add this statement after the `handleImagesLoaded` function declaration to assign it to `$scope`:

```
$scope.handleImagesLoaded = handleImagesLoaded;
```

Or just using the `handleImagesLoaded` function directly in `.success()` callback:

```
$http.get($scope.url).success(handleImagesLoaded);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks you, I have used the second solution and worked for me.